# Remove stdClass objects from array

Tags: php

I have a array like below (array 1) and I need to remove stdClass from it like in below array no. 2. Currently i'm doing it using a foreach loop, is there are better way to do that wthout looping?

**Array no.1**

```
array(3) {
  [0] => object(stdClass)#169 (4) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "59"
    ["name"] => string(13) "test"
    ["email"] => string(21) "abc@abc.com"
    ["telephone"] => string(20) "898998989"
  }
  [1] => object(stdClass)#190 (4) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "58"
    ["name"] => string(13) "test"
    ["email"] => string(21) "abc@abc.com"
    ["telephone"] => string(8) "71877858"
  }
  [2] => object(stdClass)#193 (4) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "34"
    ["name"] => string(9) "test"
    ["email"] => string(22) "abc@abc.com"
    ["telephone"] => string(13) "3189028092139"
  }
}
```

**Array no.2**

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(4) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "62"
    ["name"] => string(5) "test"
    ["email"] => string(22) "abc@abc.com"
    ["telephone"] => string(10) "898998989"
  }
  [1] => array(4) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "59"
    ["name"] => string(13) "test"
    ["email"] => string(21) "abc@abc.com"
    ["telephone"] => string(20) "71877858"
  }
  [2] => array(4) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "58"
    ["name"] => string(13) "test"
    ["email"] => string(21) "abc@abc.com"
    ["telephone"] => string(8) "3189028092139"
  }
}
```

This is what I do (casting)

```
foreach($moderationContacts as $contact)
{
    $contacts[] = (array)$contact;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: You cannot manipulate arrays without looping. Any solution will need some form of implicit looping.

Comment: @Bananam00n - I need to create a JSON object from it using json_encode

Comment: @MDeSilva You can still create a JSON object from it, no need to convert the objects into arrays.

Comment: @Diego is right, exactly why I was asking

Comment: @Diego - My purpose was different, so managed to do it with below 2 answers.

Comment: @MDeSilva I don't doubt that you had a reason for converting everything into arrays, but you just stated _I need to create a JSON object from it using json_encode_, and a simple call `json_encode()` would have done exactly that. Anyway, the important thing is that you found a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
$array = json_decode( json_encode($array), true);
```

EDIT:
I've tested this case, and it works:

```
$stdClass= new stdClass();
$stdClass->test = "foo";
$array = Array(
    "a" => Array("b","c"),
    "d" => $stdClass
);

$array = json_decode( json_encode($array), true);

var_dump($array);
```

OUTPUT

```
array
  'a' => 
    array
      0 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => string 'c' (length=1)
  'd' => 
    array
      'test' => string 'foo' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
$array = array_map(function ($v) {
    return (array) $v ; // convert to array 
}, $array);
```

Or if this data is from `json` use

```
$array = json_decode($data,true);
```