# Adding multiple files to single column in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

What to do if I want to add all the file names in single column in mysql database

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $this->input->post('pd_name'),
    'image' => $product_image,
    'image' => $product_image1,
    'image' => $product_image2,
    'created_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

this doesn't work

Comment: your array doesn't make any sense - the key `image` just holds the name of `$product_image2` - what exactly is it what you want ?

Comment: I want to insert product_image,product_image1,product_image2, into a single column called "image" in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implode the variables while storing into a single column.

```
$image_data = array($product_image, $product_image1, $product_image2);
implode('#',$image_data);
```

when you want to display just explode them.

```
explode('#',$image_data);
```

Comment: thanks, its worked. but when i want to display them an error came, "Message: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given"         public function fetch_doc()
 {
  $id= $this->uri->segment(3);
  $doc=$this->user_model->fetch_doc($id);
  


  print_r (explode(',',$doc));
  
  //$this->load->view('view_doc');
 }        public function fetch_doc($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('document');
        $this->db->from('employee_details');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
this is my model

Comment: suppose you get the result in the array $data which consist of all details.    so you get image columns  data. which is $data['image]=image_1#image_2#image_3. explode this using  function. $image_data = explode('#',$data['image]); now you will get numeric array. use for loop you will get all images  like $image_data[$i]

Comment: but this is how my array looks like     "stdClass Object ( [document] => imran.jpg,rahul.jpeg,rizwan_(2).jpeg,safdar.jpg,,wahid.jpg )"

Comment: return $result->result_array(); or else you need to remove std class object.          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420384/remove-stdclass-objects-from-array

Comment: need to remove std class object, then only I can display these images in my view page,right?

Comment: yep. once you remove it. It will be simple one value. explode it. you will get the numeric array. use foreach loop to get the images name